# RxJava2 chainning of calls

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have a below use case and I want to use rxjava2 for this .

I have a list of video with n segments. each segment has 1 form url. I need to download the each form for each segment and save in internal storage. each video is having the list of segment. segment can be any number.

I have an api for getting list of storyboard.

I have the api to get the form for each segment.

once form of 1 video is downloaded , I want to send a notification to my app.

How can `I do this in Rxjava2?

Comment: i think flatmap opertor will help, please checkout http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html

Comment: Recommended reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#dependent-sub-flows

Comment: would help if you post some code - your apis, your models, etc.